# Chassidus Tschitschkov (Czyczkow/y)

Tags: history, chasidut-hasidism

I asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34210/what-to-do-if-the-minhag-of-my-ancestors-changed) about someone who changed his minhagim and the obligations of his descendants. My great-grandfather's grandfather, was the rebbe of the town of Czyczkow, near Chojnice (Choynitz, Cheunitz) and Radún (also spelled Radin or Raden in some non-Polish sources) in northern Poland.* Does anyone know anything about this chassidus or resources which I could consult?

*My great-grandfather was named Yosef b' Mordechai, presumably after R' Yoshke of Czyczkow, his grandfather.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10919 (Dzikov)

Answer (score 1):

JewishGen.org has the following information that may be helpful.

for more info about Sieciechow Poland

Contact:

Gidi Poraz (#299209)
1 Vatikim
Bizaron, 60946
Israel

[Hebrew: שייצ'ייחוב  -  nearby Jewish communities 27 miles ENE of Radom, 8 miles ESE of Kozienice.](http://data.jewishgen.org/wconnect/wc.dll?jg~jgsys~community~-527625)